# Minimax algorithm returns tuple

Tags: python, chess, minimax

I have tried to create a minimax algorithm for chess, but it doesn't function. It now gives the error that'<' is not supported between instance of tuple and float on line 118. The tuple seems to be created when trying to recurse, which is on line 113. When using a for loop to change the tuple into integers doesn't work, because the tuple only seems to contain `NoneType`s. Does anybody know a way to fix this?

```
import chess
from numpy import Infinity
import numpy as np
import random

board = chess.Board()

def random_board(max_depth=200): 
    board = chess.Board()
    depth = random.randrange(0, max_depth)

    for _ in range(depth):
        all_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
        random_move = random.choice(all_moves)
        board.push(random_move)
        if board.is_game_over():
            break

    return board

board = random_board()

pawn_square_value = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, -20, -20, 10, 10, 5, 5, -5, -10, 0, 0, -10, -5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 10, 25, 25, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 20, 30, 30, 20, 10, 10, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

knight_square_value = np.array([-50,-40,-30,-30,-30,-30,-40,-50, -40,-20,  0,  5,  5,  0, -20, -40, -30,  5, 10, 15, 15, 10,  5, -30, -30,  0, 15, 20, 20, 15,  0,-30, -30,  5, 15, 20, 20, 15,  5,-30, -30,  0, 10, 15, 15, 10,  0,-30, -40,-20,  0,  0,  0,  0,-20,-40, -50,-40,-30,-30,-30,-30,-40,-50])

bishop_square_value = np.array([-20,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-20, -10,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  5,-10,-10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,-10, -10,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10,  0,-10, -10,  5,  5, 10, 10,  5,  5,-10,-10,  0,  5, 10, 10,  5,  0,-10, -10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,-10, -20,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-20])

rook_square_value = np.array([0,  0,  0,  5,  5,  0,  0,  0, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5,  5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  5, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])

queen_square_value = np.array([-20,-10,-10, -5, -5,-10,-10,-20, -10,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,-10,-10,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0,-10, -10,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0,-10, -5,  0,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0, -5, -10,  0,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0,-10, -10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,-10, -20,-10,-10, -5, -5,-10,-10,-20,])

king_square_value = np.array([20, 30, 10,  0,  0, 10, 30, 20, 20, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 20, -10,-20,-20,-20,-20,-20,-20,-10, -20,-30,-30,-40,-40,-30,-30,-20, -30,-40,-40,-50,-50,-40,-40,-30, -30,-40,-40,-50,-50,-40,-40,-30, -30,-40,-40,-50,-50,-40,-40,-30, -30,-40,-40,-50,-50,-40,-40,-30])

def init_evaluation():
    wp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.WHITE))
    bp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.BLACK))
    wn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.WHITE))
    bn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.BLACK))
    wb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.WHITE))
    bb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.BLACK))
    wr = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.WHITE))
    br = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.BLACK))
    wq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.WHITE))
    bq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.BLACK))

    material = 100 *(wp-bp) + 320 * (wn-bn) + 330 * (wb-bb) + 500 * (wr-br) + 900 * (wq - bq)

    pawnsq = sum([pawn_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.WHITE)])
    pawnsq = pawnsq + sum([-pawn_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.BLACK)])

    knightsq = sum([knight_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.WHITE)])
    knightsq = knightsq + sum([-knight_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.BLACK)])

    bishopsq= sum([bishop_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.WHITE)])
    bishopsq= bishopsq + sum([-bishop_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.BLACK)])

    rooksq = sum([rook_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.WHITE)]) 
    rooksq = rooksq + sum([-rook_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.BLACK)])

    queensq = sum([queen_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.WHITE)]) 
    queensq = queensq + sum([-queen_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.BLACK)])

    kingsq = sum([king_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.KING, chess.WHITE)]) 
    kingsq = kingsq + sum([-king_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)]   
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.KING, chess.BLACK)])
    
    boardvalue = material + pawnsq + knightsq + bishopsq + rooksq + queensq + kingsq

    return boardvalue

def evaluate_board():

    if board.is_checkmate() == True:
        if board.turn:
            return -9999
        else: 
            return 9999 
    
    elif board.is_stalemate() == True:
        return 0
    elif board.is_insufficient_material() == True:
        return 0 
    else: 
        return init_evaluation()


print(evaluate_board())
print(board)

board.legal_moves



#Een minimax met alpha-beta pruning: 
def minimax(bord, max_depth, depth, alpha, beta):
    if depth == max_depth or board.is_checkmate() == True: 
        return evaluate_board(), None

    best_move = None
    if board.turn == chess.WHITE:
        best_score = -Infinity
    else: 
        best_score = Infinity
    for move in board.legal_moves:
        newBoard = board.copy()
        newBoard.push(move)
        current_score = minimax(newBoard, max_depth, depth+1, alpha, beta)

        if board.turn == chess.WHITE:
            if current_score > best_score:
                best_score = current_score
                best_move = move

        else: 
            if current_score < best_score:
                best_score = current_score
                best_move = move

    return best_score, best_move  



def get_best_move():
    move = minimax(board, 3, 0, -Infinity, Infinity)
    return move

print(get_best_move())
```

Comment: `minimax` returns a tuple of 2 things.  But in `current_score = minimax(...)` you're only expecting one.  If you don't need the second, then do `current_score, _ = minimax(...)`.

Comment: We can't see line numbers on StackOverflow. Surely you could make a [mre] that doesn't include so much code.

Comment: Your minimax returns two values and you are saving those two values as your current score. Hence you are getting a tuple. As @TimRoberts said, you will actually need to save them as two separate variables to prevent this using a comma delimiter or simply just access `current_score[0]` when comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `minimax` function also returns the best_move.

If you don't need that, just remove it from the return.

If you need to use it later on, just assign a value to the other returned variable like this:

```py
import chess
from numpy import Infinity
import numpy as np
import random

board = chess.Board()

def random_board(max_depth=200): 
    board = chess.Board()
    depth = random.randrange(0, max_depth)

    for _ in range(depth):
        all_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
        random_move = random.choice(all_moves)
        board.push(random_move)
        if board.is_game_over():
            break

    return board

board = random_board()

pawn_square_value = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, -20, -20, 10, 10, 5, 5, -5, -10, 0, 0, -10, -5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 10, 25, 25, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 20, 30, 30, 20, 10, 10, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

knight_square_value = np.array([-50,-40,-30,-30,-30,-30,-40,-50, -40,-20,  0,  5,  5,  0, -20, -40, -30,  5, 10, 15, 15, 10,  5, -30, -30,  0, 15, 20, 20, 15,  0,-30, -30,  5, 15, 20, 20, 15,  5,-30, -30,  0, 10, 15, 15, 10,  0,-30, -40,-20,  0,  0,  0,  0,-20,-40, -50,-40,-30,-30,-30,-30,-40,-50])

bishop_square_value = np.array([-20,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-20, -10,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  5,-10,-10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,-10, -10,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10,  0,-10, -10,  5,  5, 10, 10,  5,  5,-10,-10,  0,  5, 10, 10,  5,  0,-10, -10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,-10, -20,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-20])

rook_square_value = np.array([0,  0,  0,  5,  5,  0,  0,  0, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5, -5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5,  5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  5, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])

queen_square_value = np.array([-20,-10,-10, -5, -5,-10,-10,-20, -10,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,-10,-10,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0,-10, -10,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0,-10, -5,  0,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0, -5, -10,  0,  5,  5,  5,  5,  0,-10, -10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,-10, -20,-10,-10, -5, -5,-10,-10,-20,])

king_square_value = np.array([20, 30, 10,  0,  0, 10, 30, 20, 20, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 20, -10,-20,-20,-20,-20,-20,-20,-10, -20,-30,-30,-40,-40,-30,-30,-20, -30,-40,-40,-50,-50,-40,-40,-30, -30,-40,-40,-50,-50,-40,-40,-30, -30,-40,-40,-50,-50,-40,-40,-30, -30,-40,-40,-50,-50,-40,-40,-30])

def init_evaluation():
    wp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.WHITE))
    bp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.BLACK))
    wn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.WHITE))
    bn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.BLACK))
    wb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.WHITE))
    bb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.BLACK))
    wr = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.WHITE))
    br = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.BLACK))
    wq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.WHITE))
    bq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.BLACK))

    material = 100 *(wp-bp) + 320 * (wn-bn) + 330 * (wb-bb) + 500 * (wr-br) + 900 * (wq - bq)

    pawnsq = sum([pawn_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.WHITE)])
    pawnsq = pawnsq + sum([-pawn_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.BLACK)])

    knightsq = sum([knight_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.WHITE)])
    knightsq = knightsq + sum([-knight_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.BLACK)])

    bishopsq= sum([bishop_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.WHITE)])
    bishopsq= bishopsq + sum([-bishop_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.BLACK)])

    rooksq = sum([rook_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.WHITE)]) 
    rooksq = rooksq + sum([-rook_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.BLACK)])

    queensq = sum([queen_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.WHITE)]) 
    queensq = queensq + sum([-queen_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)] 
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.BLACK)])

    kingsq = sum([king_square_value[i] for i in board.pieces(chess.KING, chess.WHITE)]) 
    kingsq = kingsq + sum([-king_square_value[chess.square_mirror(i)]   
                                    for i in board.pieces(chess.KING, chess.BLACK)])
    
    boardvalue = material + pawnsq + knightsq + bishopsq + rooksq + queensq + kingsq

    return boardvalue

def evaluate_board():

    if board.is_checkmate() == True:
        if board.turn:
            return -9999
        else: 
            return 9999 
    
    elif board.is_stalemate() == True:
        return 0
    elif board.is_insufficient_material() == True:
        return 0 
    else: 
        return init_evaluation()


print(evaluate_board())
print(board)

board.legal_moves



#Een minimax met alpha-beta pruning: 
def minimax(bord, max_depth, depth, alpha, beta):
    if depth == max_depth or board.is_checkmate() == True: 
        return evaluate_board(), None

    best_move = None
    if board.turn == chess.WHITE:
        best_score = -Infinity
    else: 
        best_score = Infinity
    for move in board.legal_moves:
        newBoard = board.copy()
        newBoard.push(move)
        current_score, current_move = minimax(newBoard, max_depth, depth+1, alpha, beta)

        if board.turn == chess.WHITE:
            if current_score > best_score:
                best_score = current_score
                best_move = move

        else: 
            if current_score < best_score:
                best_score = current_score
                best_move = move

    return best_score, best_move  



def get_best_move():
    move = minimax(board, 3, 0, -Infinity, Infinity)
    return move

print(get_best_move())
```